Ubuntu 24.04 LTS not available to download
ubuntu 24.04 lts noble numbat not available for download from the ubuntu.com. Did someone knows when will be available. I went to the official website to download the ubuntu 24.04 lts noble numbat but there is only 22.04 LTS
Thank you

Please give the website some time to be updated. You will get Ubuntu 24.04 eventually.

Some ISOs were only generated a little over an hour ago.. Wouldn't you prefer some QA testing to occur on them before release??   Yes if you look at the ISO QA tracker you'll see some are marked as Ready, however not all, and all get released at the same time (where possible!). Ubuntu 24.04 LTS has not yet been officially released.  FYI:  Screen to my left has an QA test install of a 24.04 ISO running currently.... The ISOs we test are available if you look for them, but if you want a tested ISO I suggest waiting.

Here you go: https://releases.ubuntu.com/noble/

Just be patient.
The Release Team has a lot of work to squeeze into one day (see the checklist and the tracking). It's more complex than push-one-button.
So releases have never been at the stroke of midnight.
The release will occur when it's ready.
Just be patient.
